# Programmatically stop navigation

Tags: c#, asp.net

In .NET (C#, specifically), how can I stop navigation?

Situation: User has clicked a link and fired off the _Click() event.

The click event fires off a save method, which verifies some information.  If any of the information isn't as desired, we want to stop the rest of the click event from occurring.

ASP.NET's built-in validation won't work in this instance.  There are multiple different ways the forms could need to be filled out (and the form is built from several different controls, each used in multiple pages) depending on the initial state of the data.  For instance, if they are hitting this form for the first time (and they've never added any information it contains before), NOTHING is required...but if they fill in anything, they must fill in (almost) everything.

With this much conditional logic in the validation, it's easier to just stick (empty) labels on the page and fill them with validation messages if needed, than to use actual validators.

Our problem is that the method that fires the Save() then moves the user to another page.

There's no return value we can use to specify 'stop navigation'...so how can I fire off the method, set the 'error' labels, and then prevent the call from going back up the stack (and sending the user away from the page)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a CustomValidator though, and handle the ServerValidate event in order to perform this custom validation?

A HTTP request may be ended by calling Response.End();
Also sounds like you should be able to just prevent the Redirect action to execute if the page is not valid.

Comment: Would if we could, but the save method has no return value, and the calling method is in a different class.  There are 2 of some 30 controls that need this validation, and we don't want to change the entire project's flow just for this.

Can't use a custom validator: no single control to link it to.

Comment: You don't need a single control to link it to; that's part of the point. Using it myself for custom complex validation, spanning relationships throughout the page

Comment: Will look into custom validators more, then.  I'd always used them with individual controls, like I would any other validator...if they aren't linked with a control, how do they indicate the control which caused the error? (Most commonly '*')

Comment: You place the CustomValidator where you want it to render a <span> if the validation does not succeed. Set the ErrorMessage property as you would normally. It will also appear in a ValidationSummary if you use one of these.

Answer (score 1):

Response.End();

Sounds like you have some spaghetti logic going on there. You want to break your validation out into a method which if it returns false, stops the processing of Save etc.

I would expect your code to look something like;

```
if (Validation())
{
    if (DoSaveFunction())
    {
         Response.Redirect("theNextPage.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
         lblWarning.Text = "Something went wrong saving the file";
    }
}
else
{
    lblWarning.Text = "Invalid inputs";
}
```

Comment: It would, except we're not exactly doing page navigation.  We've got a series of controls hosted in a single page, and the buttons navigate between them.  We have to save a control, close it, and open the next.  The complexity is because the click is handled by the page, and the save by the control.

Comment: @Ian: Is there any complexity about using Response.End() in UpdatePanels?